# Symfony 5 - "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"

Tags: sql, symfony

I'm currently face to this problem. I am really new beginer at Symfony.

Problem :
When i create a new db with cli `symfony console doctrine:database:create`, i am getting these errors :

```
In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  


In Exception.php line 18:

  could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 38:

  could not find driver
```

Iam using php 7.4 with xampp and normaly pdo_sql is installed :

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

this is my .env file config :

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

And this is my doctrine.yaml file config :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

I have been searching for hours but i cant get any solutions to solve my problem, someone has an idea ?
I'm on windows.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you happen to notice that it is complaining about postgres though it appears you are trying to use mysql?

Comment: yeah , i just realize that. Thank you very much.^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use Mysql , comment this line `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"` 
If not comment the other line

Comment: If you are using docker, don't forget install mysql drivers
`RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql`

Answer (score 15):

if you are working in Linux, probably some extensions are missing,run those command

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql php-pdo
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue with this error.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I got my `.env.local` file from a colleague and stupidly saved it without the leading dot, so Symfony was using the values from the `.env` file, which reads
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"` rather than the correct `DATABASE_URL="mysql://foo:bar@127.0.0.1:3306/baz?serverVersion=mariadb-x.y.z"` from `.env.local`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, PHP 7.4.29, xampp, windows.

For the purpose of installing Xdebug I upgraded my PHP version to 7.4.29 (previously 7.4.18), and I guess this errror occured since then. Database connexion worked before. I copied the extensions from the old php.ini to the new one and the error remained.

What resolved the problem : added this line :

```
extension_dir = "D:\programs\xampp\php\ext"
```

And activated these extensions :

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I am runing a Symofny application with docker.
When you add doctrine-bundle to your app, in Dockerfile will appear this lines what will install drivers for postgres.

You have to remove it and add this line, this will install drivers for mysql

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

I hope that helps to someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Homestead/vagrant on windows and my problem was, I wasn't able to execute this command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` on windows even though I opened a terminal as administrator

As seen on these 2 pictures I tried Cmder and Git bash and both of them failed, saying `an execption occured in driver: could not find driver`

[image]

[image]

I then solved it by SSH into my vagrant box `vagrant ssh` navigated to the working symfony folder and ran the command from there `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` and for some reason that worked !

[image]

I wish there was an easier way to debug this stuff, but I guess that's how it is working with Windows. Hope this can help someone out there

Answer (score 1):

php.ini

1. copy path
2. find the file then open it
3. delete the `;` in `extension=mysqli`

[image: modified php.ini file without the ; in extension=mysqli]

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, just uncomment the DATABASE_URL that you have on your computer either (sqlite, mysql or postresql).

Answer (score 1):

step 1 => go to Xaamp control panel then click config of Apache

step 2 => click on PHP(php.ini).browse through the file. you can able to see these extensions.

extension=bz2
extension=curl

remove ; from ;extension=pdo_pgsql and save it and close file

step 3 => now come back to your project.click on .env file and comment this line:

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

this works!

Comment: thanks man! This solution eventually worked in my case!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem to solve the problem:

- type `php --ini` to see the path to the file *php.init*
- if you are on vscode do ctr + click on the path otherwise follow the path manually on your computer to the file *php.init*  **make sure your open php.init file with admin right !!**
- edit the file and uncomment `extension=pdo_mysql`
- save and retry `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`
- type `php -m` for check if your're in list *pdo_mysql*

[here an illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ii3.png)

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to add some new insights

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I typed the following command:
**symfony console make:user User**
I solved the problem with the command:
**php bin/console make:user User**.
Wanting to create a user

Answer (score 0):

Delete or comment from .env file the line:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @mbyou Repeating it with less sophisticated formatting is not the same as adding an explanation.